# fb:// schema was overtaken by Supersonic App?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am not suer how Apple handles the registration of URL schemas for IOS Apps but a IOS game called "Supersonic" has registered fb:// as their own URL schema so whererever you click a link like fb://friends etc. IOS opens this game. and ignores if you have installed Facebook or not.

Comment: Yes it works fine when you deinstall the game and Facebook and reinstall the Facebook one more time

Comment: Sounds like something you could report to Apple. I highly doubt they tolerate this since it's not what any user would expect. Or if you want to be nice, contact the developer of the game first and suggest him to change it - probably he didn't even know the facebook app uses `fb:`

Comment: i would delete the game and badmouth them on twitter ;-)  … actually apple doesn't have any kind of public registration, and i thought FB was a bit presumptuous to use a 2-letter URI schema name, i consider them partially to blame (if it's accidental); however, it smells of an intentional grab for the Facebook clicks, which IMHO apple should slap them down for, but directly contacting them and complaining and then public shaming may have to suffice

Comment: i'm not the advocate of Facebook =) i"m sure that FB will already take some action against. it i just wanted to inform other programmers about the weird behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you posted this in the right place. But either way - try to uninstall and reinstall the facebook app. It might re-register itself as the handler for that URL type.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down the apple documentation to Implementing Custom URL Schemes,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Apple should probably discourage this abuse, but as far as I can tell the SuperSonicHD app still does this.